# i can't run a foreach loop container for an ADO NET Source contains a paradox files

Tags: ssis, ado.net, oledb, paradox

[image: when i use ado net source]

I have a lot of paradox files (*.db), i want to automatize the transfer of data containing on these files to sql server, with ado net source it works, but foreach loop doesn't.

I have configured the Foreach Loop Enumerator to use an enumerator type of Foreach ADO.NET Schema Rowset. The error it throws is

> The new connection, Paradox, is not an OLE DB connection so it can not be used by the schema rowset enumerator and therefore, will not be added to the connections list

i tried ole db source but it doesn't work.
foreach loop needs an ole db source, but when i use ole db source it doesn't read the file prompting an error.
is there a way to work with foreach loop using ado net source?
some help, if you please.
Thank you.

Is there a way to work with foreach loop using ado net source?

During execution, I receive the following error

> Opening a rowset for "VD010120" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

[image]

Comment: One file with an ADO.NET source works but when you attempt to loop over the files, it does not. Why does it not work? What error does it report? I _assume_ your error will be related to changing metadata but I don't know this. The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) has fine resources to help you identify what makes a good question

Comment: foreach loop needs an ole db source, but when i attempt to use the ole db, it can't read the file